Setting Chart.js scales y title gives compile time error " type '_DeepPartialObject"
I subscribe to data from the backend to fill my charts, when the data is received I would like to set some options so it goes like this:
this.chart.config.options.scales.y.title.display = true;

This give me a TS compile error

Property 'title' does not exist on type '_DeepPartialObject<{ type:
"linear"; } & CartesianScaleOptions & { beginAtZero: boolean;
suggestedMin?: number; suggestedMax?: number; grace?: string | number;
ticks: { format: NumberFormatOptions; precision: number; stepSize:
number; count: number; }; }> | ... 4 more ... |
_DeepPartialObject<...>'.

I know I can cast it and it works, but is there a better way than having to cast it every time, working code:
(this.chart.config.options.scales.y as CartesianScaleOptions).title.display = true;

Stackblitz that show the error:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bv1b3c

You have to define the type of chart you are using to the class Chart, which has the type definition.
...
export declare class Chart<
  TType extends ChartType = ChartType,
  TData = DefaultDataPoint<TType>,
  TLabel = unknown
> {
  ...

The valid values for chart type can be found in the source code chart.js - ChartTypeRegistry Source code
So we input the TType to be 'bar' since we are creating a bar chart here.
...
export class App implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'chartjs-test';
  chart: Chart<'bar'> = new Chart('test', { // <- changed here!
    type: 'bar',
    data: { labels: [], datasets: [] },
  });

Stackblitz Demo
